# Excel - How to sort data - based on Date, Time and ID

Tags: excel, vba, database, sorting

How to sort the data set from one table? I have input data and need to transform them into the correct output form.

I have set of X,Y coordinations with ID, Date and Time. Based on this data i need to make a "string" an with ID in the first column and then sort the data X1,Y1,X2,Y2,..(It can be separated into the cells - each value = one cell) based on Date and Time.

Here is, how my data looks like "Input data" and how I would like my "Output data" to look.

[image]

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Unfortunately SO is not a code writing service. Way things work here is: you make an effort to achieve what you want to. If you are unable to achieve your goal, you post your attempt here (in your case your VBA code.. and it doesn't matter if your code is not correct). We can then look at your attempt and try and help you. So please provide you code

Answer (score 0):

First, sort your data by PathID, Date, Time.

Then, create another column called "PathStep". This will represent the order in which each pathid goes through based on date and time. Again, you need to make sure your data is already correctly sorted. You may use a formula such as this to correctly populate the pathstep:

```
    =IF(AND(A2=A1,E2=E1),F1+1,1)
```

Or if each pathid is unique, then you can probably just use this formula:

```
    =IF(E2=E1,E1+1,1)
```

Regardless of the formula you need, drag the formula down to make your data look like this:

[image: Data]

Lastly, create a pivot table on your data. No subtotals, no Grand totals.

**Rows** = PathId

**Columns** = PathStep

**Values** = X, Y

[image: Pivot]

That's it. Update your pivot design if needed.